# Can I use # "fragment" portion of URL in the Nginx Location matcher?

Tags: nginx, webserver, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am trying to setup a location block which contains "#" character, to redirect to my backend server containing AngularJS based app. The AngularJS HashLocationStrategy introduces a "#" based routing rules. So I essentially want any URL beginning with "#" should redirect to my backend server, but Nginx routing is not able to do that.

```
...
...
location ~ \/\#\/app.*$ {
    # backend server routing
}

location / {
    # redirects to static website
}
...
...
```

But this location mapping is not working. For e.g.: `http://<hostname>/#/app` should redirect to the backend server, but it ends up redirecting to the `index.html` of the static website, due to the second location block matching `/`.

I also tried setting up `location` blocks with matchers not containing the "#" character (i.e. `location ~ ^.*app.*$ {}`), but it hasn't worked. It still redirects to the `index.html`

Is there a way for configuring Nginx to honour the first location block before looking at the second one.

Comment: The part of the URL from `#` onwards (called [the fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax)) is never sent to the server. It is used by the browser or a client-side JS application.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks a lot for the response. That clarifies why I was not able to get Nginx route based on that part. I should have looked at the Nginx access log and realized that. 

But I had not realized that and was incorrectly trying to setup a server side rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No we cannot setup a Nginx Location matcher based on the `fragment` (i.e. starting with `#`), as it never gets sent to the server. Thanks to the clarification from @RichardSmith (Refer to comments section)

> The part of the URL from # onwards (called the fragment) is never sent
> to the server. It is used by the browser or a client-side JS
> application - @RichardSmith

So the pattern I was trying to match in the Location matcher will never work as it never reaches the server.